# ApexPagesHandledException: Object type not accessible

Tags: apex, apexrest

I have written a custom apex rest endpoint which works in all my tests but I am getting a rather perplexing error when I try running on one of our customers accounts, the full error message is as follows:

> core.apexpages.exceptions.ApexPagesHandledException: Object type not
>   accessible. Please check permissions and make sure the object is not
>   in development mode: Your query request was running for too long.

Which object is not accessible? what does it mean for an object to be in "**development mode**"?

can I just ignore that and assume the only relevant bit is the part at the end that says my query took too long?

If it is a timeout are there any tools for profiling my apex to see why it took so long and/or where it was when it crashed? without anything like a line number or stack trace its really hard to tell what happened.